# <span> element going outside of <div> element

Tags: html, css, text-align, justify

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysNQV.jpg]

In above attachment, there is problem with last span(last word- "for"); it is actually going out of my gray region(this is actually div tag with class textframe).

I am really not getting the problem. The html code is also shown below. The borders for the `<span>` are shown because I just want to ask that, there is some gap present between two `<span>`, is it the reason which causing the last word problem? Then how to reduce this gap?

```
<div style="left:0pt; top:0pt; width:612pt; height:792pt; position:absolute;" class="page">
      <div style="left:103.2pt; top:189pt; width:396pt; height:156pt; position:absolute; background-color:rgb(191,191,191); overflow:hidden; border:0px Solid rgb(0,0,0);" class="textFrame">
        <p style="text-align: justify; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt;">
          <span class="ln" style="height: 14.4pt; width: 396pt;">
            <span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: F0; word-spacing: 45.9943pt; width: 197.802pt; letter-spacing: 0em; text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border: 0.1px solid red; display: inline-block;">Subject to the</span>
            <span style="font-size: 24pt; font-family: F0; width: 64.9904pt; letter-spacing: 0em; text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border: 0.1px solid green; display: inline-block;">license</span>
            <span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: F0; word-spacing: 45.9943pt; width: 133.208pt; letter-spacing: 0em; text-align: right; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border: 0.1px solid gold; display: inline-block;">terms for</span>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `box-sizing: border-box`? But I wonder what you're attempting to achieve with this in the first place. You're using a lot of fixed widths and heights.

Answer (score 6):

You have `white-space: nowrap;` set for `span.ln` this will stop it from wrapping when the content gets to the end of its parent element. It would stick out of the parent unless the parent has `overflow: hidden;` set, in which case the text would be obscured. Remove the `white-space: nowrap;` rule to allow the spans to wrap. You may also get weird layout issues as the inner spans are `display: inline-block;` which means they appear as a block element within some inline content, you may want to remove this too.

Unless the spans are actually next to each other in the source any white space will be rendered as a space between them whilst they are either `display: inline;` which is the default display for span elements or `display: inline-block;` as the inner spans are set up in this example (the style is visible in the style attribute of the element). To get rid of the space between elements with `display: inline-block;` set you need to remove the white-space (spaces, tabs and new lines) between the spans in the source.

Comment: We have followed your instructions but the third <span> jumps to the second line which is not the expected behavior. And if i remove the display:inline-block; the difference between words is not proper. Will you please post edited source code?

Comment: I want those three span should be in same line. Actually this text is from my other text document and i want same look in html as that of text doc.

Comment: I strongly recommend against inline styles unless you like maintenance nightmares, I have however modified your html to work, drop the `display:inline-blocks;` add some spaces in the spans, add `word-spacing` to the middle div http://jsfiddle.net/Hm4zx/1/... If two lines is what you want, if not you will need to adjust the `word-spacing` or the width of the container, bearing in mind that people can control the text size in their browser so using `em` would be better than absolute sizing in `pt`.

Comment: I would advise against it. Web page is a web page a text document is a text document. A HTML web page is not a static word document. Upload a PDF if you want to display the actual document. Otherwise if you want to create a web page to show the content contained in the document do so, but make a web page and not a poor replica of a text document.

Answer (score 1):

Personally the thing that worked for me ,
I gave the parent element a "word-wrap: break-word" and the specified the width for the child span element.