# CSS span or p goes outside of div

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to replicate stackoverflow-like design and ran into problem.

```
<div class="flex-grow-0 pd-around-m">  # line 1
    <div class="flex-col fill-row mr-around-s"> # line 2
        <div class="flex-row fill-row"> # line 3
            <div class="flex-col justify-center mr-around-m"> # line 4
                //Buttons
            </div>
            <span>
                //Long Text!!
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="answer-bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.fill-row {
    width: 100%
}

.flex-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.mr-around-m {
    margin: 1rem;
}

.justify-center {
    justify-content: center;
}
```

When I enter long text in `<span>`, `<div>` in `line 2`, `line 3` goes out of `div` box in `line 1`.

I tried adding `white-space: pre-line` to `div` in `line 2` and directly at `span` but still text goes out of the box.

**How can I keep the text inside parent `div`?**

[image]

**navigation bar on the left has property `width:20%` but gets squashed. Is this because of the textbox problem I asked above?**

**EDIT**
https://jsfiddle.net/pzcu2yjn/ 
Here's a replication of my problem. if you make the text in `span` short enough, `navbar` and menu will have some empty space in the left maintaining 20% of the screen. however, if you leave the long text as it is, it gets squashed and 20% gets ignored

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the problem, that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/rgw1s8vq/20/ can you explain what is happening in the fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pzcu2yjn/ Here's a replication of my problem. if you make the text in `span` short enough, `navbar` and menu will have some empty space in the left maintaining 20% of the screen. however, if you leave the long text as it is, it gets squashed and 20% gets ignored

Comment: ok, so you need the 20% to be intact and the longer text should be wrapped into next line ?

Comment: Yep thats exactly what I need. I asked this question because navbar's 20% was interfered by the text..

Comment: @J.S.C I have added my answer with the reason, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

> 1. On using `flex` it is good to provide `width` for left and right container since container will not know what it should when content increases.
> 2. Once you have the width assigned to the `right` container that is when you can use `wrap` functionality so the wrap works only for right container and it doesn't have no impact on less container. `overflow-break-word;`

NOTE:

I have removed unwanted code from the code, you can put it back it has no impact if those are needed.

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border-right: 0.05rem solid var(--main-border-color);
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.pd-around-m {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div>
      menu1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-grow-0 pd-around-m">
    <div class="flex-col fill-row mr-around-s">
      <div class="fill-row">
        <span>
                  AaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                  </span>
      </div>
      <div class="answer-bottom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `overflow: hidden;` to prevent the text from going outside of your div.
There's a very similar question with a precise answer:
[<span> element going outside of <div> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839345/span-element-going-outside-of-div-element)

Comment: tried adding `overflow:hidden` but doesnt work. I added fiddle to replicate my problem